# OpenGL Rotation issue

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, rotation

#### Solution:

strtod instead of atof solved it.
Thanks!

*TODO: make this an answer for acceptance*

---

I'm loading a value from an XML file that tells how much the texture should be rotated.

It looks like this:

```
string rotv = ItemElem->FirstChild("Rotation")->FirstChild()->Value();
rotation = -(atof(rotv.c_str()))*57.2957795;
```

In my level editor the textures are rotated properly; pi equals 180 degrees and so on.
But in the engine; they are not, it seems like the decimals are ignored. So for example, a texture that should be rotated 3.14 radians is only rotated 3 radians and so on.
I've tried many different approaches to make sure the decimals are included, but I can't get it to work.

I rotate the textures like this:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->GetImage());
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);

glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.5, 0.5, 0);
glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(-0.5, -0.5, 0);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
```

The value in the xml file uses a dot instead of coma and I convert it like this, I also store the decimals separately just for debugging.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < rotv.size(); x++)
     {
          if (afterComa)
          {
                  int temp = (int) rotv[x] - '0';
              if (temp <10 && temp >= 0)
              {
                  decimals[decimalPos] = temp;
                  decimalPos++;
              }
              else
              {
                  break;
              }

          }
         if (rotv[x] == '.')
         {
             rotv[x] = ',';
             afterComa = true;
          }
      }
```

float decimalValue =  decimals[0]/10 + decimals[1]/100 +  decimals[2]/1000 +  decimals[3]/10000 +  decimals[4]/100000 +  decimals[5]/1000000;

The decimals are stored properly and I add them to the rotation value but it still doesn't help.

Comment: What is the type of `rotation` is it declared as an `int` ?

Comment: Is there locale info in the XML and what character is used for the decimal place?

Comment: The rotation is a float, the XML uses a point for the decimal place.
I updated the post with more info about when I "convert" the value.

Comment: Have you tried using strtod (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/). It has better localization so you don't have to change the "." to ",".'

Comment: @Orujimaru: We don't "SOLVE" questions here on StackOverflow, we accept answers.

Comment: @Lucian: Write that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @datenwolf: I wrote the comment as an answer. Please see below.

Comment: @Lucian: Well, I'm not the questioneer, that's Orujimaru.

Comment: @Orujimaru: Please answer Lucuian's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/) instead of atof. It has better localization so you don't have to change the "." to ","

Answer (score 1):

Break it out, make sure what you *think* is happening is *really* happening:

```
string rot_str = ItemElem->FirstChild("Rotation")->FirstChild()->Value();
float rot_rad = atof( rotv.c_str() );
float rot_deg = rot_rad * 57.295779;
rotation = rot_deg;
```

Use your debugger to step through each operation and verify the values are as expected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
I did that however my debugger won't show me the value, I don't know why.

Comment: @Orujimaru please check if the project is running in debug-mode to see the values.

Comment: Yeah, it's not running in debug mode, I'm moving the solution between many computers and the one I'm currently on doesn't support my debug settings for some reason.